# Is this a phase change in a gas under Thermodynamic Equilibrium?

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image: Molar Density vs Pressure]

The above graph shows the molar density (i.e. `n/V` from `PV=nRT`) of a gas plotted against pressure. There are two regions with good fit to a linear relationship which I have coloured green and blue (though these are all from a single set of measurements. The visual distinction is just to highlight where the linear fit applies)

My rusty physical chemistry knowledge suggests that the regions where there is a linear fit are in Thermodynamic Equilibrium as the Ideal Gas law would appear to be holding. Given that we have two linear regions I would also conclude that there is a phase change and that the whole is actually in Thermodynamic Equilibrium when we account for the phase change (i.e. `n` is different between the two regions)

Is this naïve analysis based on a foggy recollection of Phys Chem lectures from 20 years ago correct or is there another explanation for this data (and if so what is the explanation)

*Update*

To clarify on the hypothesized phase change. The suggestion is that this phase change is a `X + X <=> X2` phase change where `X` and `X2` are both gaseous but the X2 form is only thermodynamically stable at lower temperatures (which correspond to the lower pressures). i.e. not the more common gas-liquid phase change

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it necessarily suggests a phase change.  It just seems to me that, at the higher pressures, we are seeing non-ideal gas behavior setting in.

Comment: If it is a phase change as somebody else has hypothesized, it would be a phase change in a ~15-25% component of the gas mixture.

Comment: If there were a phase change (condensation), the molar density would be increasing faster, not slower, because liquid would be forming.

Comment: If it is a phase change (dimerization) then 1 mole will be turning into 0.5 moles so the molar density would be decreasing faster because the dimers are still a gas and assuming they are an ideal gas they will still (mostly) behave as points with mass and elastic collisions

Comment: You didn't say anything about a chemical reaction occurring.  A chemical reaction is not the same thing as a phase change.  A phase change involves a change in the state of aggregation of the matter.

Comment: It's not a chemical reaction - if the hypothesis I am trying to stress is correct it is rather a dipole association which can be viewed as a different gas phase, but still a gas phase